# Adjective for a person who doesn't want any sympathy

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for an adjective that describes a person who doesn't want any sympathy or empathy for himself/herself.

Comment: This is hard, there are plenty of words for people who can get by without sympathy from others, but someone who "doesn't want" sympathy from others, now that's a hard one.

Comment: @Rahul Tandon Since your question has been put on hold (FYI, you can improve the question and ask for a reopen), and I think I know what you  are looking for, here are some suggestions: [**callous**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/callous) *"without human warmth or emotion".* and if not, try [**impassive**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/impassive) *"not revealing or affected by emotion"*.

Answer (score 1):

You could say someone is "too proud" or "too stubborn" to accept sympathy.

They could be "abrupt" or "abrasive". Maybe "standoffish".

"Independent" could also be used for a positive spin.

Answer (score 0):

**self-reliant**  [free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-reliant)

> Reliance on one's own capabilities, judgment, or resources;
>   independence.

Answer (score 0):

A '**stoic**' is someone who does not seek sympathy. 'Stoic' is also the adjective so can be used descriptively.

> If you say that someone is a **stoic**, you approve of them because they do not complain or show they are upset in bad situations.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stoic)

> One who practises repression of emotion, indifference to pleasure or pain, and patient endurance.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/190673?redirectedFrom=stoic#eid)

> Bit-by-bit the **stoic, infallible image** of sporting heroes is turning

[The Courier - 15 March 2018](http://www.thecourier.com.au/story/5301634/press-box-much-needed-change-to-sports-hero-image/)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you could say **antipathetic**, but I think that is just a general distaste and aversion to something.

Comment: Please make your answer more comprehensible by providing dictionary definitions or other corroboration for the the logic behind your word choice. Example sentences with the word's usage might also be helpful.